# Ruby puts string and integer on same line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puts

I just started learning Ruby and uncertain what is causing the error.  I'm using ruby 1.9.3

```
puts 'What is your favorite number?'
fav = gets 
puts 'interesting though what about' + ( fav.to_i + 1 )

in `+': can't convert Fixnum into String (TypeError)
```

In my last puts statement, I thought it is a simple combination of a string and calculation.  I still do, but just not understanding why this won't work

Answer (score 13):

In Ruby you can often use "string interpolation" rather that adding ("concatenating") strings together

```
puts "interesting though what about #{fav.to_i + 1}?"
# => interesting though what about 43?
```

Basically, anything inside the `#{}` gets evaluated, converted to a string, and inserted into the containing string. Note that this only works in double-quoted strings. In single-quoted strings you'll get exactly what you put in:

```
puts 'interesting though what about #{fav.to_i + 1}?'
# => interesting though what about #{fav.to_i + 1}?
```

Answer (score 3):

`( fav.to_i + 1 )` returns an Integer, and ruby does not do implicit type conversion. You have to convert it yourself by doing `( fav.to_i + 1 ).to_s` to be able to add it to the string.

Comment: ok so is it sort of like strings go with strings?  and integers can't mix with strings?  Thank you for the solution!

Comment: Yes, sort of: [Here's a good read about it](http://www.rubyfleebie.com/ruby-is-dynamically-and-strongly-typed/).